# My phpadmin showing blank page, since i've try to install Moodle

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

When i start Apache this is error_log

[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.218446 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 235726] AH01906: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.218528 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 235726] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.318983 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 235727] AH01906: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.319020 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 235727] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.319170 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 235727] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.337552 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 235727] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1q mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 15 14:29:05.337607 2022] [core:notice] [pid 235727] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'

Am not a spcialist so help me understand what's going !

I've clear my chrome's cache first, it don't resolve the problem
I've try changing the memory_limit to 1GB, it's still blank after save, restart and refreshing !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your Apache server SSL certificate. Error messages in the log file indicate that the certificate is a CA certificate, which means that it is a CA certificate and not a server certificate. In addition, the identifier in the certificate does not match the server name.

This can cause problems when trying to access the PHPAdmin page over HTTPS, as the browser may not trust the certificate and refuse to display the page. One possible solution to this problem could be to create a new SSL certificate for your server that is for the server name, not the CA certificate. You can then configure Apache to use this new certificate, which will allow you to access the PHPAdmin page via HTTPS without any errors.

It is also worth noting that error messages in the registration log indicate that you are using an older version of Apache (2.4.54), PHP (5.34.1) and OpenSSL (1.1.1q). It may be worth considering upgrading to the latest versions of these components to make sure you have the latest security updates and patches.